# Airflow DAGs file directory tree is not updated?

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

Airflow is working on Google Cloud Composer, and version is 1.10.2-composer.

I make a mistake that I upload DAGs file (tutorial.py) to a directory, like this tutorial.py/tutorial.py.

When I removed it and upload again.
I saw the error info from stackdriver logging.

> [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/tutorial.py'

How do I fix it?

P.S.
I have to upload tutorial.py with new name like tutorial_test.py.
But I don't want to do it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have encountered this problem because you set  '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/tutorial.py' as the destination. However, the [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/storage/plugins/import#--destination) '--destination' sets a folder of destination, not a file. In this case, '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/tutorial.py' is a folder name. Composer thus creates a path '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/tutorial.py'.

Therefore, use '--destination' [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/storage/plugins/import#--destination) in the correct way.

When you drop files in the folder '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/tutorial.py', this folder is deleted in GCS automatically at the same time because it becomes empty, so you can not access this folder anymore. The second command puts the file 'tutorial.py' in the folder '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/'.

Please refer to this [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/124067145) for more references.

Comment: Thank you. Before execute command, I will read Doc carefully.